# How use from global variable in exec

Tags: python

I have written the following code in Python 3.6.2:

```
user=0
def test():
    global user
    d = locals()
    exec('user=1', globals(), d)
test()
print(user)
```

I want to use variable `user` (it is global) in `exec` and change its value to `1` and in `print(user)` print its value, but it is printing `0`.

How can fix it?

Comment: There is an answer to your question, but I bet that whatever you are trying to do is not the right way to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable `global` in the `exec`uted code:

```
>>> user = 0
>>> def test():
...     exec('global user; user=1', globals())
... 
>>> test()
>>> print(user)
1
```